Is it possible to override an attribute in a method to use that instead of the attribute applied to the class?
I have created a custom attribute. That attribute may be applied to a class or a method. And depending on the parameters, it can take different actions.
Well, I have this attribute applied to the class using this [ProAuthorize(Enums.RolesEnum.SuperAdministrador, Enums.RolesEnum.Administrador)] however, that same attribute is also defined in a method of the same class, called this way: [ProAuthorize(true, true)].
The fact is that only the first definition is taken into account (at class level), and not the method level definition.
When debugging, and examining the attribute context, I found this:

See that the custom attribute is twice in the metadata. The first shown is the one defined at class level and the second one is the defined at method level.
My solution could be to use the context to get the last attribute, but I am wondering if there is a way the attribute to appear only once in the metadata. That way, when the method is called, the right attribute wlll be applied.
This is how I declared the attribute:

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class ProAuthorizeAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter

Thanks

Is it a custom attribute which you use in your code elsewhere? Then sure, you need to handle conflicts like this, because you allow them.

Yes... I have used this: if (context.ActionDescriptor.EndpointMetadata.OfType<ProAuthorizeAttribute>().LastOrDefault() is not ProAuthorizeAttribute rightAttribute)     return new ForbidResult();. It seems it is the only solution.
